# What is the best practice for define in C++?

Tags: c++, standards, c-preprocessor

I was wondering if there are any official recommendations regarding the use of define in c++ language, precisely is it best to define in your header or your source file?
I am asking this to know if there are any official standards to live by, or is it just plain subjective... I don't need the whole set of standards but the source or a link to the guidelines, will suffice.

---

LATER EDIT:
What is the explanation of the fact that `const` and `constexpr` have become the status quo, I am referring to `define` used as means of avoiding repetitive typing, it is clear in my mind that programmers should use the full potential of the c++ oop compiler. On the other hand, if it is so feared, why not remove it altogether? I mean, as far as I understand, `define` is used solely for conditional compilation, especially, as in making the same code work on different compilers.
Secondary, tiny question, the potential for errors is also the main reason why java doesn't have true C-style `define`?

Comment: Least scope. If it's only used in one C file, put it there. If it's used in multiple, put it in a header file.

Comment: It's subjective, but there are conventions that you would be foolish not to follow. Always always use ALL_CAPS names for macros (and for the reasons I give in [stop the constant SHOUTING](http://accu.org/index.php/articles/1923) never use ALL_CAPS names for non-macros)

Comment: That's not _official_, but just avoid it like hell with c++. There are rare use cases.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: that's a bit excessive... of course if inline functions or `const` variables or templates or whatever are a good alternative they should be preferred, but I see nothing bad in a very local (=defined just before use, undefined immediately after) macro to save some typing and avoid errors due to copy-pasted code.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Which advantages would a local macro for e.g. constant values have over a `const` declared variable? Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: who talked about constant values? `const` is perfectly fine for that. I'm talking about stuff like building expressions on the fly - say, you have to copy some fields between two structs, where in one they are say - named with a prefix. Or you have to dump some fields of a struct logging/debugging purpose, adding their name before. In general, whenever the `#` and/or `##` operators are required it's difficult to find good alternatives in C++ (although, when stuff gets complicated it's usually better to generate the code through an external script written in a decent language).

Comment: @MatteoItalia That was just a sample. Macros (even used locally) are simply much more error prone than regular variable definitions or inline functions due to their text processing only nature, that leaves a lot of space for unexpected results. I mentioned there are _rare_ valid use cases. Tokenizing is one of these, as you mentioned.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: when what you need is *exactly* text processing there are no alternatives, besides generating code through external means. Again, there's no alternative in C++ for what the operators `#` and `##` do (with all their deficiencies).

Comment: Usually we use `const double PI = 3.1415926` instead of `#define PI = 3.1415926`.
There are two advantages of using `const`.

 1. compilers will check the type of `PI` if you use `const`.
 2. Some IDE or tools perform better with `const`.

Comment: "Why not remove it altogether", do you mean break old code which uses them?  No way! Then you might as well switch to another language. Also, there are valid uses, for which #define is needed, with no modern, safer alternative.

Comment: Could you provide an example of valid use, besides cross compilation needs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A short list of `#define` use guidelines for C++, points 2, 4, 6 and 7 actually address the question:

1. Avoid them
2. Use them for the the common ["include guard" pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in header files
3. Otherwise, don't use them, unless you can explain, why you are using `#define` and not `const`, `constexpr`, or an inline or a template function, etc, instead.
4. Use them to allow giving compile time options from compiler command line, but only when having the option as run-time option is not feasible or desirable.
5. Use them when whatever library you are using requires using them (example: disable [`assert()` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) )
6. In general, put everything in the most narrow possible scope. For some uses of `#define` macros, this means `#define` just before a function in .cpp file, then `#undef` right after the function.
7. The exact use case for `#define` determines if it should be in `.h` or in `.cpp` file. But note that most use cases are actually in violation of 3. above, and you should actually not use `#define`.

Comment: Thank you for you kind answear!